# Simple and basic python csv file opening

Tags: python, path, file-permissions

```
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-b64111033e13> in <module>
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 #Reading the data
----> 4 df1 = pd.read_csv(r"D:\downloads\data analysis dataset\zippedData\tmdb.movies.csv")
      5 
      6 

d:\final anaconda\envs\learn-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    684     )
    685 
--> 686     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    687 
    688 

d:\final anaconda\envs\learn-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    450 
    451     # Create the parser.
--> 452     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    453 
    454     if chunksize or iterator:

d:\final anaconda\envs\learn-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py
```

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
#Reading the data
df1 = pd.read_csv(r"D:\downloads\data analysis dataset\zippedData\tmdb.movies.csv")


df1.head()  #to see the first five rows of the
```

Comment: Can you format your code and traceback please?

Comment: "Permission error" means the file is protected and you do not have access to it. Attempting to access it from Python is immaterial; you would get the same error if you simply tried to copy the file.